# How long an attachment link will be available on Facebook Messenger

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

When discussing on Facebook Messenger, you can upload files and send them to the person you're discussing with.  I'm actually developing a Messenger Bot (see [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform)) and therefore, I'm trying to find the limits of this upload tool.

I found that it's not possible to upload files bigger than 25MB (I put [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382639/facebook-messenger-bot-size-of-video-attachment-how-big-can-it-be/41767632#41767632) how I found this information).

However, I couldn't find for how long these attachments are available once uploaded?  Indeed, Facebook Messenger is uploading the file on server and is sending a link to that resource in the communication.  But I couldn't find if this link will be available forever or if access to it will be limited in time (and therefore, I guess the attachment would be deleted after this duration).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to get a response to my question, I uploaded a file and checked regularly its availability.  Since I couldn't check every minute, I got a +/- 1 day precision but it seems that files stay available between 2 and 3 days.